# Varnish MISS on some URL's, but HITS on other

Tags: magento2, varnish

We are using Magento 2 with Varnish cache

We only get Varnish Cache HIT on very few /catalogsearch/result/ pages, and we really can not figure out why we don't get cache HIT on all /catalogsearch/result/ pages.

Please help us in the right direction :-)

Ex.

we always get HIT on this url

- https://www.babygear.dk/catalogsearch/result/?q=bog

We always get MISS on a lot of other search queries

- https://www.babygear.dk/catalogsearch/result/?q=black
  https://www.babygear.dk/catalogsearch/result/?q=box
  https://www.babygear.dk/catalogsearch/result/?q=box

Here is our varnish.vlc

```
# VCL version 5.0 is not supported so it should be 4.0 even though actually used Varnish version is 5
vcl 4.0;

import std;
# The minimal Varnish version is 5.0
# For SSL offloading, pass the following header in your proxy server or load balancer: 'X-Forwarded-Proto: https'

backend default {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "8080";
    .first_byte_timeout = 600s;
}

acl purge {
    "127.0.0.1";
}

sub vcl_recv {


    if (req.method == "PURGE") {
        if (client.ip !~ purge) {
            return (synth(405, "Method not allowed"));
        }
        # To use the X-Pool header for purging varnish during automated deployments, make sure the X-Pool header
        # has been added to the response in your backend server config. This is used, for example, by the
        # capistrano-magento2 gem for purging old content from varnish during it's deploy routine.
        if (!req.http.X-Magento-Tags-Pattern && !req.http.X-Pool) {
            return (synth(400, "X-Magento-Tags-Pattern or X-Pool header required"));
        }
        if (req.http.X-Magento-Tags-Pattern) {
          ban("obj.http.X-Magento-Tags ~ " + req.http.X-Magento-Tags-Pattern);
        }
        if (req.http.X-Pool) {
          ban("obj.http.X-Pool ~ " + req.http.X-Pool);
        }
        return (synth(200, "Purged"));
    }

    if (req.method != "GET" &&
        req.method != "HEAD" &&
        req.method != "PUT" &&
        req.method != "POST" &&
        req.method != "TRACE" &&
        req.method != "OPTIONS" &&
        req.method != "DELETE") {
          /* Non-RFC2616 or CONNECT which is weird. */
          return (pipe);
    }

    # We only deal with GET and HEAD by default
    if (req.method != "GET" && req.method != "HEAD") {
        return (pass);
    }


    # Bypass shopping cart, checkout
    if (req.url ~ "/checkout") {
    return (pass);
    }
    
    # Bypass health check requests
    if (req.url ~ "/pub/health_check.php") {
        return (pass);
    }

    # Set initial grace period usage status
    set req.http.grace = "none";

    # normalize url in case of leading HTTP scheme and domain
    set req.url = regsub(req.url, "^http[s]?://", "");

    # collect all cookies
    std.collect(req.http.Cookie);

    # Compression filter. See https://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/FAQ/Compression
    if (req.http.Accept-Encoding) {
        if (req.url ~ "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|gz|tgz|bz2|tbz|mp3|ogg|swf|flv)$") {
            # No point in compressing these
            unset req.http.Accept-Encoding;
        } elsif (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "gzip") {
            set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "gzip";
        } elsif (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "deflate" && req.http.user-agent !~ "MSIE") {
            set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "deflate";
        } else {
            # unknown algorithm
            unset req.http.Accept-Encoding;
        }
    }

    # Remove all marketing get parameters to minimize the cache objects
    if (req.url ~ "(\?|&)(gclid|ff|fp|cx|ie|cof|siteurl|zanpid|origin|fbclid|mc_[a-z]+|utm_[a-z]+|_bta_[a-z]+)=") {
        set req.url = regsuball(req.url, "(gclid|ff|fp|cx|ie|cof|siteurl|zanpid|origin|fbclid|mc_[a-z]+|utm_[a-z]+|_bta_[a-z]+)=[-_A-z0-9+()%.]+&?", "");
        set req.url = regsub(req.url, "[?|&]+$", "");
    }

    # Static files caching
    if (req.url ~ "^/(pub/)?(media|static)/") {
        # Static files should not be cached by default
        #return (pass);

        # But if you use a few locales and don't use CDN you can enable caching static files by commenting previous line (#return (pass);) and uncommenting next 3 lines
        unset req.http.Https;
        unset req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto;
        unset req.http.Cookie;
    }

    return (hash);
}

sub vcl_hash {
    if (req.http.cookie ~ "X-Magento-Vary=") {
        hash_data(regsub(req.http.cookie, "^.*?X-Magento-Vary=([^;]+);*.*$", "\1"));
    }

    # For multi site configurations to not cache each other's content
    if (req.http.host) {
        hash_data(req.http.host);
    } else {
        hash_data(server.ip);
    }

    # To make sure http users don't see ssl warning
    if (req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto) {
        hash_data(req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto);
    }
 
    if (req.url ~ "/graphql") {
        call process_graphql_headers;
    }
    

}

sub process_graphql_headers {
    if (req.http.Store) {
        hash_data(req.http.Store);
    }
    if (req.http.Content-Currency) {
        hash_data(req.http.Content-Currency);
    }
}

sub vcl_backend_response {

    set beresp.grace = 3d;

    if (beresp.http.content-type ~ "text") {
        set beresp.do_esi = true;
    }

    if (bereq.url ~ "\.js$" || beresp.http.content-type ~ "text") {
        set beresp.do_gzip = true;
    }

    if (beresp.http.X-Magento-Debug) {
        set beresp.http.X-Magento-Cache-Control = beresp.http.Cache-Control;
    }

    # cache only successfully responses
    if (beresp.status != 200) {
        set beresp.ttl = 0s;
        set beresp.uncacheable = true;
        return (deliver);
    } elsif (beresp.http.Cache-Control ~ "private") {
        set beresp.uncacheable = true;
        set beresp.ttl = 44400s;
        return (deliver);
    }

    # validate if we need to cache it and prevent from setting cookie
    if (beresp.ttl > 0s && (bereq.method == "GET" || bereq.method == "HEAD")) {
        unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
    }



   # If page is not cacheable then bypass varnish for 2 minutes as Hit-For-Pass
   if (beresp.ttl <= 0s ||
       beresp.http.Surrogate-control ~ "no-store" ||
       (!beresp.http.Surrogate-Control &&
       beresp.http.Cache-Control ~ "no-cache|no-store") ||
       beresp.http.Vary == "*") {
        # Mark as Hit-For-Pass for the next 2 minutes
        set beresp.ttl = 120s;
        set beresp.uncacheable = true;
    }

    return (deliver);
}

sub vcl_deliver {
    if (resp.http.X-Magento-Debug) {
        if (resp.http.x-varnish ~ " ") {
            set resp.http.X-Magento-Cache-Debug = "HIT";
            set resp.http.Grace = req.http.grace;
        } else {
            set resp.http.X-Magento-Cache-Debug = "MISS";
        }
    } #else {
      #  unset resp.http.Age;
   # }

    # Not letting browser to cache non-static files.
    if (resp.http.Cache-Control !~ "private" && req.url !~ "^/(pub/)?(media|static)/") {
        set resp.http.Pragma = "no-cache";
        set resp.http.Expires = "-1";
        set resp.http.Cache-Control = "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0";
    }

    unset resp.http.X-Magento-Debug;
    unset resp.http.X-Magento-Tags;
    unset resp.http.X-Powered-By;
    unset resp.http.Server;
    unset resp.http.X-Varnish;
    unset resp.http.Via;
    unset resp.http.Link;
}

sub vcl_hit {
    if (obj.ttl >= 0s) {
        # Hit within TTL period
        return (deliver);
    }
    if (std.healthy(req.backend_hint)) {
        if (obj.ttl + 3000000s > 0s) {
            # Hit after TTL expiration, but within grace period
            set req.http.grace = "normal (healthy server)";
            return (deliver);
        } else {
            # Hit after TTL and grace expiration
            return (miss);
        }
    } else {
        # server is not healthy, retrieve from cache
        set req.http.grace = "unlimited (unhealthy server)";
        return (deliver);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit tough to judge what's really going on, because there's both a Varnish cache in front of Magento and Cloudflare as the CDN.

### A no-cache/no-store Cache-Control value

What I am seeing in general for your searches, is the following `Cache-Control` value:

```
cache-control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
```

Based on this value, Varnish will decide not to cache. In the response headers of must of your search results you will see that `Age: 0` is set. This means that Varnish doesn't hold the value in cache.

### A cached search result that shouldn't be cacheable

However, weirdly enough https://www.babygear.dk/catalogsearch/result/?q=bog does have a an `Age` header with a value greater than zero:

```
age: 38948
```

This means it's been in cache for 38948 seconds. But really, this shouldn't be happening, because the page is not supposed to be cacheable.

### Making search results cacheable:

Please make sure you have a `Cache-Control` header that allows caching, if you want to cache search results.

Example:

```
Cache-Control: public, s-maxage=3600
```

### Debugging using Varnishlog

If you really want to know what happens in behind the scenes in Varnish, you can perform some debugging using the `varnishlog` binary.

You could run the following command to get debug output:

```
varnishlog -g request -q "ReqUrl eq '/catalogsearch/result/\?q=bog'"
```

This will print some very verbose logs on how Varnish treats the URL that causes the hit. You can add this output to your question, and I can try to examine what's going on.

> FYI: I wrote a very detailed blog post about `varnishlog` a couple of years ago. Please go to https://feryn.eu/blog/varnishlog-measure-varnish-cache-performance/ to have a look, and to learn.

### What's Cloudflare doing?

All that being said, I have no clue what the impact of Cloudflare is on the cacheability of the website. The `varnishlog` output will give us some insight, but if those results diverge from reality, Cloudflare is probably getting in our way.

Keep this in mind while debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Inside **vcl_recv** Add

```
 # Bypass search requests
    if (req.url ~ "/catalogsearch") {
        return (pass);
    }
```